# variable substitution in if statement

Tags: unix, ksh, aix

I am trying to execute the below

```
if [[ $1 == 'R' ]]
then
    echo "Running the recovery steps..."
    for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6
    do
        head -${i} cons.txt | tail -1 | read -r r${i}f1 r${i}f2 r${i}f3 r${i}f4 r${i}f5 r${i}f6 r${i}f7 r${i}f8 r${i}f9;
        if (( ${Time} >= ${r${i}f1} && ${Time} < ${r${i}f2} ))
        then
            sed "s/$r$if3}/`echo $r$if3 | cut -c1-4`/;s/$r$if4/`echo $r$if4 | cut -c1-4`/;s/$r$if5/`echo $r$if5 | cut -c1-4`/;s/$r$if6/`echo $r$if6 | cut -c1-4`/;s/$r$if7/`echo $r$if7 | cut -c1-4`/;s/$r$if8/`echo $r$if8 | cut -c1-4`/;s/$r$if9/`echo $r$if9 | cut -c1-4`/" cons.txt > cons.txt.tmp && mv cons.txt.tmp cons.txt
        fi
    done
fi
```

but the inside if condition gives me error. I believe I am using wrong set of braces here but can't seem to figure out the correct way

```
trim.sh[6]: " ${Time} >= ${r${i}f1} && ${Time} < ${r${i}f2} ": 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameter expansion is not recursive (or repeated, or inside-out) in `< ${r${i}f2}`, so this can't work.

You could use some convoluted code using `eval` to construct variable names before expansion, but that's a can of worms. What about simply unrolling the six element loop?

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to do directly the variable inside the variable reference.

```
${r${i}f2}
```

You have to use the indirect reference. Try the below code it will work. Using eval we can done this.

```
if [[ $1 == 'R' ]]
then
    echo "Running the recovery steps..."
    for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6
    do
        head -${i} cons.txt | tail -1 | read -r r${i}f1 r${i}f2 r${i}f3 r${i}f4 r${i}f5 r${i}f6 r${i}f7 r${i}f8 r${i}f9;
        eval var1=r${i}f1
        eval var2=r${i}f2

        eval val1=\$$var1
        eval val2=\$$var2

        if (( ${Time} >= $val1 && ${Time} < $val2 ))
        then
            sed "s/$r$if3}/`echo $r$if3 | cut -c1-4`/;s/$r$if4/`echo $r$if4 | cut -c1-4`/;s/$r$if5/`echo $r$if5 | cut -c1-4`/;s/$r$if6/`echo $r$if6 | cut -c1-4`/;s/$r$if7/`echo $r$if7 | cut -c1-4`/;s/$r$if8/`echo $r$if8 | cut -c1-4`/;s/$r$if9/`echo $r$if9 | cut -c1-4`/" cons.txt > cons.txt.tmp && mv cons.txt.tmp cons.txt
        fi
    done
fi
```